# Roles in CakePHP Auth Component

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm trying to use roles in the CakePHP Auth component. The roles would be user, admin, super-admin, etc. I'm having difficulty with placing a conditional in each controller based off the user role. I tried the following and it didn't work:

```
function  beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add');

        if($this->Auth->user('roles') == 'admin') {
            $this->Auth->allow('index', 'add', 'edit', 'delete');
        } 
        elseif($this->Auth->user('roles') == 'super-admin') {
            $this->Auth->allow('index', 'add', 'edit', 'delete', 'make_super_admin', 'privileges'); //Note difference in superadmin priviledges

        }
```

The problem is with the conditional. I want the function to go in each controller (UsersController, PatientsController, AdmissionsController, etc.) and based off the user role, give different permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Placing this logic in the `beforeFilter()` of the `AppController` class should do the trick.

Another thought that I had was that maybe you should consider using the Acl component in conjunction with the Auth component.  The Acl component will give you out-of-the-box granular control over every action in every controller.  If used correctly, you'd only have to set permissions on the actions for each role and the type of access-control checking that you are currently trying to do will be automated.

The book has an excellent tutorial on how to make this work.  I'm using it in my application and it's well worth the time invested to setup and understand how it all works.  Reference below.

[CakePHP Book :: Simple Acl controlled Application](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)

Comment: +1 For the AcL tip. You definitely want to use the ACL functionality for this as this does exactly what you want.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the ACL component because I've tried the tutorial several times and also various other plugins unsuccessfully. If there's something beyond the book that you've used, I'd greatly appreciate it. Plus if you use the book tutorial, it does not edit a user's acl when you change their role.

Comment: @Chris When a role change occurs you can easily detect this in your code and do an `Acl::allow()`. Acl is the way to go, I'm confident of this as are others here.  Furthermore, you can edit the `acl` table directly by getting a reference to it via `ClassRegistry::init()`. The Aco sample creation code found in this tutorial does this and gives you insight on how to gain additional functionality when working with the component. It's worth another shot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your problem, but if you want to allow every action you have to use `*` instead of nothing:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add');

    if($this->Auth->user('roles') == 'admin') {
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    } elseif($this->Auth->user('roles') == 'super-admin') { 
        $this->Auth->allow('*');
    }
}
```

If you want to set those permissions for every controller it would be the best to put it in your AppController so it will affect everything.

Comment: I had that in there originally, not sure why it isn't there now. That didn't answer the question though. The problem is with the conditional. I want the function to go in each controller (UsersController, PatientsController, AdmissionsController, etc.) and based off the user role, give different permissions.

Comment: If you have different permissions per controller you only can set them manually in every controller or use ACL as suggested by @generalopinion.

Comment: @generalopinion You've about convinced me even though I'm having difficulty understanding how to do it. If someone could recommend a good (beyond the cake one) tutorial or write a good one, I'm sure they would get a lot of applause.